# How can i POST data with graphene_django?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm completely new to GraphQL and graphene and i just finished the [graphene_django tutorial](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/)

I understand how to get data from server, which is pretty easy, but i don't know how to do create or update

do i need to use django rest framwork for POSTs or is it possible to use just graphene to get and put data?

Comment: I have done the mutation (Insert) how to update the existing data using mutation ?

Answer (score 2):

To create or edit objects in graphQL you have to use something called mutation, for more information and how to use it read [this from graphQL page](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations).

Now in Django you have something called schema.py where you put your Class query. Here we also put the mutation class to create our mutations like we created our queries. Your question is too broad so I leave you a tutorial where explain how to use mutations with Django. But should be something like:

```
class CreateMessageMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
        message = graphene.String() #Parameters to create our model

    message = graphene.Field(MessageType) #This field is required to show our message

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, **kwargs):
        message = args.get('message', '').strip()

        obj = models.Message.objects.create(message=message)

        return CreateMessageMutation(status=200, message=obj)
        #Here we return the object to show what we have created 

class Mutation(graphene.AbstractType):
    create_message = CreateMessageMutation.Field()
```

and the another schempa.py:

```
class Query(ingredients.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    # This class will inherit from multiple Queries
    # as we begin to add more apps to our project
    pass

class Mutation(ingredients.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

https://github.com/mbrochh/django-graphql-apollo-react-demo#add-mutation

Comment: If you had a payload would help a lot.